# Why does my WPF view not work without code-behind when applied through a DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, viewmodel, code-behind

I'm working on a large WPF project using MVVM.  We're currently still deciding the extent to which we'll use code-behind, but so far we've gotten along fine with none at all (except for InitializeComponent on windows).  However, I recently started using typed DataTemplates to apply views to my view models, and it seems these views, like windows, do not work without the InitializeComponent call, when, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) article, I thought they would.  The DataTemplate just declares a view.  When I delete the view's code-behind file, the view model renders completely blank.  When I leave it in, it's fine.  Any ideas why I might be seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

First, you may be overlooking something important: I used that article heavily when learning MVVM/WPF as well, and I never thought it suggested eliminating InitializeComponent calls from the View.cs.

In fact, doing a quick search reveals the following (under Relaying Command Logic) [emphasis mine]:

> Every view in the app has an empty
>   codebehind file, **except for the
>   standard boilerplate code that calls
>   InitializeComponent in the class's
>   constructor.**

I've been applying the same pattern you describe while leaving the default code-behind for each view in place, and so far it's smooth sailing. :)

Further: If you check out the definition for the default `InitializeComponent()`, you'll see that the generated code contains the following statement:

`System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);`

I haven't tested to make sure this is the case, but I'll wager a fiddle of gold against your soul that preventing that line from executing is going to affect the rendering of your view... ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I am definitely perfectly happy leaving the code-behind files in place if it's required to make things work smoothly, and I agree it seems odd that it **would** work without running the line you posted.  However, you left out a very important line from the article, immediately after the line you quoted:

Comment: **"In fact, you could remove the views' codebehind files from the project and the application would still compile and run correctly."**  You can download and test his solution, and it indeed works without the .cs files.  So I'd really like to know why it works in his case and not in mine, as I'm sure at the very least the answer will teach me something about how this all works.

Comment: @sou You're right, he does say that, and I missed it... but I took a copy of the demo app and deleted the code-behind files for the All Customers and New Customer views, and, though the app compiled and ran, the views did not render! Between you, Josh, and me, at least one of us must be missing something... :)

Comment: Wait wait wait... What are we thinking? Of course StackOverflow [already has the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841646/xaml-without-the-xaml-cs-code-behind-files)! That said, after minimal fiddling I'm not sure it works, either. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Hm, you're right!  Could've sworn I had it working previously.  It runs without the code-behind files but the tabs are blank.  I guess it isn't possible and I'm not sure why the author claims it is.  Regarding the other Stack Overflow link, if you put the XAML for your view model's appearance directly within the <DataTemplate> tag, no other files or code-behind is needed.  But as soon as you break it out into a UserControl (which is good to do to clean things up and keep related styles and such together), it's required.  At least now I know and I can leave the files be.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to djacobson, even the solution by Josh Smith that I referenced in my question cannot render its views without the code-behind, so the line stating this can be done is misleading.  It seems the only way to avoid code-behind for your views is by not putting them into UserControls at all, but just keeping the XAML directly within a < DataTemplate > tag.